# Get an environment variable by name in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-template-engine

I'm using Jenkins Template Engine and I'm facing the following issue:

Let's say I want to have a library step that uploads artifacts to Artifactory. This step should set as a property the URL of the git commit. I want that each project will provide this URL in a `pipeline_config.groovy` file, not hard-coded in the step.

The thing is, that this URL is composed of some fixed string, plus a dynamic value, namely `env.GIT_COMMIT`: e.g.: `http://specific-server.com/project/${env.GIT_COMMIT}`

Eventually, I want the step to be as follows:

```
// upload.groovy

def call() {
   def props = config.git_url
}
```

and the pipeline_config file:

```
// pipeline_config.groovy

libraries {
  artifactory
  {
     git_url = "http://specific-server/project/${env.GIT_COMMIT}"
  }  
}
```

So the question comes down to this: How can I instruct the library step to retreive some dynamic variable from the pipeline_config.groovy file?

@steven-terrana

Comment: I have no experience with the template-engine but could the load step work for you?

Comment: Don't think so.. This method evaluates a script within a file in the workspace. That's not the case.. Thanks though

Answer (score 1):

JTE can resolve the `env` var within the pipeline configuration, assuming the environment has been set for the build.

If the GIT_COMMIT comes from the project being built, you could determine that information from within the library step using the git cli and then concatenate the base-url provided from the pipeline configuration.